# Spring AuthenticationManager and Circular Dependencies Problem on SecurityConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm learning about security config in a tutorial and will go to the JWT Authentication material. I have a problem with circular dependencies error in AuthenticationManager. I've checked everything but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I hope you guys can help me with the problem I'm having.

**..>bookcatalog>config>SecurityConfig.class**

```
package com.bluedev.bookcatalog.config;

import com.bluedev.bookcatalog.security.filter.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import com.bluedev.bookcatalog.security.provider.UsernamePasswordAuthProvider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String V1_URL = "/v1/**";
    private static final String V2_URL = "/v2/**";

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UsernamePasswordAuthProvider usernamePasswordAuthProvider;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.userDetailsService(appUserService).passwordEncoder(appConfig.passwordEncoder());
        auth.authenticationProvider(usernamePasswordAuthProvider);
    }

    protected UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter buildUsernamePasswordAuthFilter(String loginEntryPoint){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(loginEntryPoint, successHandler, failureHandler, objectMapper);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(V1_URL, V2_URL).authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(buildUsernamePasswordAuthFilter("/v1/login"), org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**..>bookcatalog>security>filter>UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
package com.bluedev.bookcatalog.security.filter;

import com.bluedev.bookcatalog.dto.LoginRequestDTO;
import com.bluedev.bookcatalog.exception.BadRequestException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private final AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
    private final AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl, AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        this.successHandler = successHandler;
        this.failureHandler = failureHandler;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        LoginRequestDTO dto = objectMapper.readValue(request.getReader(), LoginRequestDTO.class);

        if(StringUtils.isBlank(dto.getUsername()) || StringUtils.isBlank(dto.getPassword())){
            throw new BadRequestException("username & password must be provided.");
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(dto.getUsername(), dto.getPassword());

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        this.successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authResult);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        this.failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, failed);
    }

}
```

**..>bookcatalog>security>provider>UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.java**

```
package com.bluedev.bookcatalog.security.provider;

import com.bluedev.bookcatalog.service.AppUserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class UsernamePasswordAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        UserDetails appUser = appUserService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if(!passwordEncoder.matches(password, appUser.getPassword())){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid.username.password");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(appUser, null, appUser.getAuthorities());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

**..>bookcatalog/security/handler/UsernamePasswordAuthSuccessHandler.java**

```
package com.bluedev.bookcatalog.security.handler;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class UsernamePasswordAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        resultMap.put("result", "SUCCESS");

        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), resultMap);
    }
}
```

**..>bookcatalog/security/handler/UsernamePasswordAuthFailureHandler.java**

```
package com.bluedev.bookcatalog.security.handler;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class UsernamePasswordAuthFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        resultMap.put("result", "FAILURE");

        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), resultMap);
    }
}
```

**Error Result**

```
2022-06-17 18:31:06.226 ERROR 18092 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  securityConfig (field private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.bluedev.bookcatalog.config.SecurityConfig.authenticationManager)
└──<-──┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you please post the code for `com.bluedev.bookcatalog.config.SecurityConfig.authenticationManager` and tbh, after looking at your code, there is a lot of bad things so im just going to say that the tutorial you are following seems to be quite bad. I would recommend not following any tutorial and instead read the official spring security documentation. Its really good.

Comment: I added some files related to my problem. I still don't know if what I learned is true or not, because I'm still new to learning spring, but I'm not the type of person who believes in tutorials 100%, I will definitely dig into spring material further.@Toerktumlare

Comment: if you are a beginner ALWAYS go for the official documentation on all libraries you choose to use. If that doesnt help you, go for tutorials, but make sure they are up to date. Maximum 6 months old. Everything else is outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below line from `SecurityConfig`

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

And modify the `buildUsernamePasswordAuthFilter` function to use `authenticationManagerBean()` function

```
protected UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter buildUsernamePasswordAuthFilter(String loginEntryPoint){
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(loginEntryPoint, successHandler, failureHandler, objectMapper);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());

    return filter;
}
```